# Can I speed up my special round function?

Tags: c#, performance

I have this function:

```
int round(double val) {
    if (val >= 0) {
        return (int)Math.Floor(val + 0.5);
    }
    return (int)Math.Ceiling(val - 0.5);
}
```

I call it in my program many times, I mean MANY times, so every milisecond of it's running time matters. Is there any way of having it faster than it is now? Thx

EDIT:

The function is part of algorithm for computing the tangent direction of a line in an image. It is taken from academic article. As it handles the angles in radian values, it uses small, precise numbers.

I/O examples:

```
0 -> 0
1 -> 1
1.1 -> 1
1.51 -> 2
-0.1 -> 0
-1 -> -1
-1.1 -> -1
-1.51 -> -2
```

EDIT2:

According to comments, I change the examined function to this one:

```
int round(double val) {
    return (int)Math.Round(val, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
}
```

The updated question is: Is the Math.Round function the fastest way of rounding?

Comment: Didn't you just implement `Math.Round` with `MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero`?

Comment: Based on your output this is `Math.Round` with `MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero`

Comment: Well when I take a deep look at it, it seems that I did... :-) But can you propose the fastest way of doing such rounding?

Comment: @Jarda did you have a profile measurement stating that it is that specific round which needs optimization ? There is no need for pre-mature optimization if it isn't the case

Comment: @Sehnsucht I did the profiling (on my original function). The inclusive percentage of this function is 16.5%, I call that function 1 405 000 times in single app run and the inclusive time is 3746ms. As I wrote in the Q - every milisecond counts here... Possibly it will improve when I use the AwayFromZero rounding...

Comment: @Jarda If this is a performance-critical application, don't use C# and .NET. Use C++.

Comment: @Dai it is not performance-critical, but I need to speed it up to acceptable level... I have chosen the C#.NET because of simplicity and user-friendliness when implementing structurally complicated process containing non-trivial algorithms... And I hate handling with those pointers and dereferences...

Comment: Done a quick "bench" (I don't claim writing "perfect bench" whatever that could be) and on 1.5M calls the diff / iteration is less than 1 tick (so less than 100 nano sec) you can see it [there](https://dotnetfiddle.net/wmBXp6). And even without that, all calls taking around 0.2 sec (that's pretty far away of the 3746 ms so maybe other parameter are at play than this)

Comment: Thanks for the effort. Possibly the hardware plays big role... I'll do some testing to check it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can speed it up. This is many times faster:

```
        if (val >= 0)
        {
            return (int)(val + 0.5d);
        }
        return = (int)(val - 0.5d);
```

You avoid all those Math library stuff. Problem is, does it really matter? For 1500000 conversions the time of You first function is 18ms. Your EDIT2 function is 36ms. This function is 4ms.

According to this measurement the processor can compare two doubles, add two doubles and convert one in about 2,5ns. But if it does not have it in the cache, reading from main memory can take 100ns. Measuring can be misleading sometimes.

Here is complete code

```
#region stopky

        public class Stopky
        {
            [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
            private static extern bool QueryPerformanceFrequency(out long frequency);

            [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
            private static extern bool QueryPerformanceCounter(out long ticks);

            protected static double frequency = -1;

            public void setStart()
            {
                QueryPerformanceCounter(out tickStart);
            }

            public double getTimeFromStart
            {
                get
                {
                    QueryPerformanceCounter(out tickNow);
                    double time = (tickNow - tickStart) / frequency;
                    return time;
                }
            }

            private long tickStart;
            private long tickNow;

            public Stopky()
            {
                if (frequency < 0)
                {
                    long tmp;
                    QueryPerformanceFrequency(out tmp);

                    if (tmp == 0)
                    {
                        throw new NotSupportedException("Error while querying "
               + "the high-resolution performance counter.");
                    }

                    frequency = tmp;
                }

                setStart();
            }

            public void Show()
            {
                MessageBox.Show(this.getTimeFromStart.ToString());
            }


        }

        #endregion




        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            double[] examples = new double[] { 0, 1, 1.1, 1.51, -0.1, -1, -1.1, -1.51 };

            int totalCount = 1500000;

            double[] examplesExpanded = new double[totalCount];

            for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < examplesExpanded.Length; ++i)
            {
                examplesExpanded[i] = examples[j];

                if (++j >= examples.Length) { j = 0; }
            }

            int[] result1 = new int[totalCount];
            int[] result2 = new int[totalCount];
            int[] result3 = new int[totalCount];

            Stopky st = new Stopky();
            for (int i = 0; i < examplesExpanded.Length; ++i)
            {
                result1[i] = (int)Math.Round(examplesExpanded[i], MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
            }
            st.Show();
            st = new Stopky();
            for (int i = 0; i < examplesExpanded.Length; ++i)
            {
                double val = examplesExpanded[i];
                if (val >= 0)
                {
                    result2[i] = (int)Math.Floor(val + 0.5);
                }
                result2[i] = (int)Math.Ceiling(val - 0.5);
            }
            st.Show();
            st = new Stopky();
            for (int i = 0; i < examplesExpanded.Length; ++i)
            {
                double val = examplesExpanded[i];
                if (val >= 0)
                {
                    result3[i] = (int)(val + 0.5d);
                }
                else
                {
                    result3[i] = (int)(val - 0.5d);
                }
            }
            st.Show();

            for (int i = 0; i < totalCount; ++i)
            {
                if(result1[i] != result2[i] || result1[i] != result3[i])
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("ERROR");
                }
            }
            MessageBox.Show("OK");

        }
```

Some notes

- i < examplesExpanded.Length is slightly faster than i < totalCount, although it is counter intuitive. The reason is, range check can be avoided.
- Release can be significantly faster than Debug (here is the difference not big)

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly the answer, that I was looking for... I've done a little benchmark test and your version of the round function is 10x faster than my original function and 20x faster than the one with AwayFromZero rounding

Comment: That will round -0.5 => 0 and -1.5 => -1, unlike the positive cases where 0.5 >= 1, 1.5 => 2.0

If you would like it to be symmetric you can use: 
`val >= 0 ? (int)(val +0.5f) : -(int)(0.5f-val)`

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the inbuilt `Math.Round` method?

```
int round(double val) {
    if (val >= 0) {
        return Math.Round(val, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
    }
    return Math.Round(val, MidpointRounding.ToEven);
}
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.round(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I don't think, that your proposal is correct - for example, when I have val=-5, then yours will return -6 but mine will return -5... and there is problem with positive values as well

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood what you are trying to do. Are you able to edit your question with some example inputs and outputs and why your method is written like it currently is?

Comment: Looking at your edit, I don't think you need to neagtive check, just `Math.Round(val, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);`

Comment: Well when I take a deep look at it, it seems that I did... :-) But still there is a question if there is a better way of implementing it. I mean, is the Math.round function the fastest way of rounding numbers?

Comment: Without doing some performance testing, it is probably the fastest way without implementing a lower level rounding algorithm. And depending on your application and the hardware you are running it on, I doubt you would achieve much of a performance increase anyway.

Comment: Ok, I'll check the performace increase when using the AwayFromZero rounding and I may check your answer correct.

Comment: After doing the benchmark, this is not correct answer for my question. The built-in AwayFromZero rounding function is much slower than my original one.